# GDB cannot access memory I mmap

Tags: c++, ubuntu, gdb, mmap

In my code I mmap some memory and can read and write from it. For some reason when I run the code in gdb though, gbd can't access it. What's the problem?

The code in question

```
cout << "creating temp" << endl;
int *temp = mmap(... PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE ...);
*temp = 5;
cout << "temp = " << *temp << endl;
```

The output when ran

```
creating temp
temp = 5
```

My gdb prompt

```
(gdb) n  
77        *temp = 5;  
(gdb) p temp  
$1 = (int *)0x7fffec4000;   
(gdb) x temp  
0x7fffec4000: cannot access memory at 0x7fffec4000  
(gdb) n  
78        cout << "temp = " << *temp << endl;
(gdb) x temp  
0x7fffec4000: cannot access memory at 0x7fffec4000
(gdb) n
temp = 5
(gdb) x temp  
0x7fffec4000: cannot access memory at 0x7fffec4000
```

Comment: Is that really a valid address? It reads like `deadbEEF` at a page-address.

Comment: Any reason you changed the language? (and then remove the tag of the wrong language).

Comment: I wrote an easily distinguishable address for the simplistic example. The actual address is a random address along the lines of 0x7fffec4000

Comment: I'm writing in c++ but my problem comes code that's not specific to c++

Comment: You should use the actual address. Such like the one used are missleading; good programmers trigger to patterns.

Comment: What type of object is being mmapped? I've heard accounts of `ptrace` failing to access memory that has been mmapped to device special files. Also, can you add a tag that identifies your OS?

Comment: @MarkPlotnick _"I've heard accounts"_ -> Actually, it's true. I've experienced it myself while developing on Linux for a device with memory-mapped registers and a badly coded kernel driver. The code [here](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/d52bd54db8be8999df6df5a776f38c4f8b5e9cea/mm/memory.c#L3871) rejects reads or writes to `VM_IO/VM_PFNMAP` memory unless the driver defined a `vm_ops->access` getter function that encodes the knowledge about how to read that region of memory. I ended up hacking GDBserver into translating reads from that region into reads of its own device memory mapping.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3640095/gdb-cant-access-mmapd-kernel-allocated-memory