# Viewing Memory in GDB Outside of Process Space (mmap)

Tags: c, gdb, mmap, raspberry-pi

QUESTION:

For educational purposes, I'm in the process of trying to understand exactly how the RaspberryPI interfaces with its GPIO headers. I have a simple program that control an LED on an expansion board that works well. However, I wanted to use GDB to see the program changing bits in the mapped control registers. Normally I would do something like this in GDB:

```
x /t 0x20200000
```

But this seems to result in the following error, presumably as the target memory is not in the process space:

```
0x20200000: Cannot access memory at address 0x20200000
```

I tried mapping a memory region but didn't seem to help.

```
mem 0x20200000 0x20208192
```

I also true to write a function to call from GDB, but couldn't figure out how to write something that returned entire block of memory I am interested in so can view as binary (I don't want to peek each byte as write bits are quite spread out over area). *Is there any way I can do this in GDB?*

### Supporting Code

Memory addresses to map:

```
#define BCM2708_PERI_BASE   0x20000000
#define GPIO_BASE           (BCM2708_PERI_BASE + 0x200000)
```

Pointer to mapped memory:

```
static volatile uint32_t *gpio ;
```

Mapping routine:

```
int gpio_init (void)
{
  int      fd ;
  uint8_t *gpioMem;

  if ((fd = open ("/dev/mem", O_RDWR | O_SYNC) ) < 0)
  {
    fprintf (stderr, "gpio_init: unable to open /dev/mem: %s\n", strerror (errno)) ;
    return -1 ;
  }

  if ((gpioMem = malloc (BLOCK_SIZE + (PAGE_SIZE-1))) == NULL)
  {
    fprintf (stderr, "gpio_init: malloc failed: %s\n", strerror (errno)) ;
    return -1 ;
  }

  if (((uint32_t)gpioMem % PAGE_SIZE) != 0)
    gpioMem += PAGE_SIZE - ((uint32_t)gpioMem % PAGE_SIZE) ;

  gpio = (uint32_t *)mmap((caddr_t)gpioMem, BLOCK_SIZE, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE,  MAP_SHARED|MAP_FIXED, fd, GPIO_BASE) ;

  if ((int32_t)gpio < 0)
  {
    fprintf (stderr, "gpio_init: mmap failed: %s\n", strerror (errno)) ;
    return -1 ;
  }

  return 0 ;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The physical memory address `0x20200000` is being mapped into your process address space at an address stored in the variable `gpio`, so that's the address you should be examining in `gdb`.  Just print the contents of `gpio` after `gpio_init()` has been called and use that value.

As an aside the way the mapping is done is confused.  There is no need to allocate a memory block with `malloc` and then map over it, and it also fails to close the file descriptor.  That entire function could be better written as:

```
int gpio_init (void)
{
  int      fd ;

  if ((fd = open ("/dev/mem", O_RDWR) ) < 0)
  {
    fprintf (stderr, "gpio_init: unable to open /dev/mem: %s\n", strerror (errno)) ;
    return -1 ;
  }

  gpio = mmap(NULL, BLOCK_SIZE, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_SHARED, fd, GPIO_BASE) ;

  if (gpio == MAP_FAILED)
  {
    fprintf (stderr, "gpio_init: mmap failed: %s\n", strerror (errno)) ;
    close(fd);
    return -1 ;
  }

  close(fd);
  return 0 ;
}
```

Comment: I'm glad I wasn't the only one who looked at that and saw the MAP_FIXED + malloc and wondered what was going on.

Comment: Thanks for re-write, will test. Without your changes, executing this 'x /t gpio' results in '0xABCDEF: Cannot access memory at address 0xABCDEF'. Would you expect your changes to alter this?

Comment: @Scruffers: That sounds like `gpio_init()` has not been called yet.

Comment: @caf - I'm sure it has. Reading this thread, perhaps what I am trying is not possible? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/654393/examining-mmaped-addresses-using-gdb?rq=1

Comment: @Scruffers: Ahh yes - you're right, the `/dev/mem` device obviously doesn't implement ptrace accessors.