# Print in program works but gdb says "Cannot access memory at address ..."

Tags: c++, c, gdb, gdbserver

I have the following code:

```
struct A
{
  int fieldA;
  int fieldB;
};

A *a = (A *) ptr;

cout << a->fieldA; // Works fine
cout << a->fieldB; // Works fine
```

`ptr` is a `char *` object that points to somewhere in memory.  The object that is stored in memory at address `ptr` is an `A` object.  The structure is written by another process in memory that is shared between the processes.  In the process where I have the above code, the shared memory is read only.

The program being executed in on a remote target.  I run the program on the target using gdb-server, and I connect to the server from my development machine using gdb.

The print statements correctly prints the expected value.  However, when I print the fields of the structure from gdb by doing `p a->fieldA`, I get "Cannot access memory at address ...".  This doesn't make sense because I would expect that since my program can access the contents of the structure, so should gdb.

Why is this happening?

Comment: _"I would expect that since my program can access the contents of the structure, so should gdb"_ That doesn't necessarily hold. For one thing, the value of `ptr` and the value of `a` can trivially change over time.

Comment: Let me guess, `ptr` is not just an ordinary pointer allocated with `malloc` or `new`, but for example some "device memory" allocated by a driver function, or something like that?

Comment: @Mats To be specific, ```ptr``` is pointing to memory that is being written by another processor.  The code where I am reading the contents at ```ptr``` is running on another processor.

Comment: @Lightning The address that ```ptr``` is pointing to is not changing.  I observe that if I step through the print statements line-by-line, before ```cout```, gdb gives the error and after ```cout``` gdb gives the error.  Yet from the program, the correct value is printed.

Comment: Right, so the memory is NOT "regular" memory, like I said. At least in Linux, "device memory" (memory allocated by device drivers, and similar) is not considered as readable by debugger [don't ask me exactly why, but I've run into this a few times when debugging in OpenCL, where the memory is a mapped OpenCL buffer, perfectly accessible by the processor code, but not by the debugger]

Comment: It's not really device memory.  It is a region in DDR that is shared with the two processors.

Comment: One tip to help with gdb is to turn off optimizations (-O0), which sometimes makes memory more accessible

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I didn't fully explain the entire background.  The memory region I am trying to access is a mmap()'d region, and gdb cannot view such regions.  The following solution [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/654393/examining-mmaped-addresses-using-gdb) solves the problem:  write a function that prints from the region, and call that function from gdb.