# Mapping Reserved High Memory to User Space via remap_pfn_range

Tags: c, linux, memory-management, linux-kernel

Arch=x86_64

I am working through a DMA solution following the process outlined in this question,
[Direct Memory Access in Linux](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/647783/direct-memory-access-in-linux)

My call to `ioremap` successfully returns with an address, pt.

In my call to `remap_pfn_range` I use, `virt_to_phys(pt) >> PAGE_SHIFT`, to specify the pfn of the area generated by the `ioremap` call.

When the userspace application using `mmap` executes and the call to `remap_pfn_range` is made, the machine crashes.  I assume the mapping is off and I am forcing the system to use memory that is already allocated (screen glitches before exit), however I'm not clear on where the mismatch is occurring. The system has 4 Gigs of Ram and I reserved 2Gigs by using the kernel boot option `mem=2048M`.

I use `BUFFER_SIZE=1024u*1024u*1024u` and `BUFFER_OFFSET=2u*1024u*1024u*1024u`.

putting these into `pt=ioremap(BUFFER_SIZE,BUFFER_OFFSET)` I believe pt should equal a virtual address to the physical memory located at the 2GB boundary up to the 3GB boundary.  Is this assumption accurate?

When I execute my kernel module, but I change my `remap_pfn_range` to use `vma->vm_pgoff>>PAGE_SHIFT` as the target pfn the code executes with no error and I can read and write to the memory.  However this is not using the reserved physical memory that I intended.

Since everything works when using `vma->vm_pgoff>>PAGE_SHIFT` I believe my culprit is between my `ioremap` and the `remap_pfn_range`

Thanks for any suggestions!

The motivation behind the use of this kernel module is the need for large contiguous buffers for DMA from a PCI device.  In this application, recompiling the kernel isn't an option so I'm trying to accomplish it with a module + hardware.

Answer (score 1):

> My call to ioremap successfully returns with an address, pt.
>
> In my call to remap_pfn_range I use, virt_to_phys(pt) >> PAGE_SHIFT,
>   to specify the pfn of the area generated by the ioremap call.

This is illegal, because ioremap reserves virtual region in vmalloc  area. The virt_to_phys() is OK only for linearly mapped part of memory.

> putting these into pt=ioremap(BUFFER_SIZE,BUFFER_OFFSET) I believe pt
>   should equal a virtual address to the physical memory located at the
>   2GB boundary up to the 3GB boundary. Is this assumption accurate?

That is not exactly true, for example on my machine
 cat /proc/iomem

```
...
00001000-0009ebff : System RAM
...
00100000-1fffffff : System RAM
...
```

There may be several memory banks, and the memory not obligatory will start at address 0x0 of physical address space.

This might be usefull for you [Dynamic DMA mapping Guide](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/DMA-API-HOWTO.txt)

Comment: Thanks, I'll look into this and report back.  I appreciate your insight, brevity, and tone.